# unable to calculate the correct result of equation according to BODMAS in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

How to perform the calculation according to BODMAS rule if i set the formula in json like `a x (b + c) - (d - e) ÷ ((f + g) – h)`

Where

`a=86`,
`b=15`,
`c=20`,
`d=74`,`e=37`,`f=8.5`,`g=10`,`h=87`,

How i can use the BODMAS method for getting the expected result

Please help.

Comment: Its returning `28.49` in the console

Comment: working fine m can you check your actual code

Comment: sorry actually it was my mistake my string is in the format like this 1000-3+25*75-23/100

Comment: So you have something that tries to add parenthesis in there right? Like you have a function in between that will convert your input to `((((1000-3)+25)*75)-23)/100`. Can you show this function? And can you show what's the expected intermediate result **with** the parentheses (not only the return value).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let result = eval("(1000-3+25*75-23)/100");
console.log(result)
```

This returns 28.49

Comment: Me too,  its returning 28.49

Comment: Please do not post answers that do not answer the question. We have close vote reasons exactly for the case of Questions about a problem that can not be reproduced. Answering such question with only "works here" deosn't help anyone.

Comment: sorry actually it was my mistake my string is in the format like this 1000-3+25*75-23/100.